# Using token in feedback form

Tags: php, forms, security

Went to check http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html in order to make a feedback form more secure. With my very limited skills came up with something like this:

Suppose there is form.php (the form) and form-processing.php (the script used to send it).
In the beginning of the form.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

...and in the beginning of the form itself echo the token into a hidden field:

```
<form method="POST">    
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

In the beginning of the form-processing.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
    }
else {
  die( "Invalid token" );
}
```

Would this do the job safely?

Comment: Would this do *what* job safely? What’s the intent of this token?

Comment: The idea is to check that the data processed by form-processing.php has been submitted at the same website by form.php. I would guess there are better ways to do this and if so, please let me know.